# Using tensor-flow queue to pass input to pretrained inception model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using the pretrained inception model in tensor-flow for image recognition. I would like to use a `tf.FIFO` to pass input to the inception graph.

I currently pass the values as

```
input = #numpy array of image
softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
predictions = session.run(softmax_tensor, {'Cast:0': input})
```

Now I would like to use a `tf.FIFO` feed in the values, instead of feed dict. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible way is to use [variable sharing](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope), loading the old weights into the new graph with the input queue. Just make sure the variable names are consistent. Often you can just modify the old graph generation code to use the new input.